# Facebook JS SDK JSON result error

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

JSON response from the following: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/111166108932649

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Musician/band",
      "name": "Andre Nickatina",
      "created_time": "2011-04-22T20:18:08+0000",
      "id": "111166108932649"
    }
  ]
```

When I try to extract a field with this:

```
FB.api('/me/likes/111166108932649',function(response) {
    if( response.data ) {

            $('#result').append(response.data[0].name);
    } else {
        alert('ERROR!');
    }
```

It tells me in the console that:  TypeError: response.data[0] is undefined

Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: You may not be getting back from the FB.api call what you think you are.  Try `console.log(response);` above the `if(reponse.data) {` line.

Comment: I tried that and it isn't generating anything in the log, how do I go about figuring out what this is outputting?  This is the JSON it shows in the API Explorer.

Comment: If nothing is generated in the log, then there's probably an authentication issue or something else.  I'd need to see a more complete implementation to further assist.

Comment: After adding access_token to the URL I can now submit it directly in the browser and get the correct response.
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/108133539208421?access_token={token}

However, when running from my application(with same URL minus the access_token) it seems like the access_token is not being generated or being passed correctly after the user logs in.  What code is needed to force this to happen?